# Pass data from server to client

Tags: c#, asp.net

I fill a dimensional array in a function (server-side) then Client has to allow for saving data.

How can I pass this array to client and then to server? This array maybe too large and I can’t add it in session.

```
List<List<string>> friend = new List<List<string>>();
```

Comment: I don't know what I do? I have a array in server that I have to send it client and then send it to server!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that when you use HTTP, **the client requests** and **the server responds**. No matter what paradigm you use (eg ajax) this will be what actually happens under the hood. So there is no way for the server to cause an action, if the client does not initiate it.

I would suggest to setup a [REST endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) and then call it from the client using javascript. This REST endpoint could return data, in a format that the clilent would understand and could display. Usually, data are being transfered using the JSON format. The client, could then make a second REST request, sending the JSON data back to the server.

Perhaps [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call) could help you.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Perhaps you could describe your case in more detail... Then I could give a better scenario...